# Why is Remote Debugging for Safari Mobile so inconsistent?

Tags: ios, macos, mobile, safari, remote-debugging

I've been developing JavaScript for many years with `OSX` and `Mobile Safari`, and I've noticed Remote Debugging has ALWAYS been extremely inconsistent.

Currently, I am running **Safari 10.0** on **El Capitan 10.11.6**, and **iOS 10.0.2** (the latest), and I'm not getting it to work AT ALL. I actually hadn't attempted to use this feature for several months before recently, so not sure if maybe the feature is just completely broken now.

In the past, if you quit Safari Mobile, and quit Safari (desktop) both, then started them back up, sometimes it would begin working, and then sometimes continue to not work (shows "No Inspectable Applications", or device doesn't show in menu). I am NOT changing any settings between these steps, and I know they are what they should be according to documentation, and tips I've read.

Develop menu is on. Web Inspector is enabled. Fraudulent Website Warnings is off (someone suggested this has something to do with it). iOS is open, and on a web page.

I know other people who've encountered this exact problem again and again. It seems that it is clearly a bug that Apple needs to resolve. I know how to use [weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/), and this is a great workaround; however, it is highly irritating to waste my time trying to get this to work several (many) times, and then have to give up, and go set up weinre every time (it happens a lot).

So! I've read through several StackOverflow topics on this (can't find them ATM), but none of them that I've seen specifically address the spottiness of this issue, or how to solve it once and for all.

Comment: Because Apple ships buggy code

Comment: And continues to allow developer bugs to be unresolved for years.